# How to make Provider and Navigator work together?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I use `Provider` for state management and for separate business logic from UI.

I have put some `Provider` above `MaterialApp` so can access everywhere in app (for example user info).

**But** [You don’t want to place ChangeNotifierProvider higher than necessary (because you don’t want to pollute the scope).](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)

So I try put some `Provider` which are only use on some pages lower in widget tree.

For example in my purchase item flow I can have: `SelectItemPage` => `ConfirmItemPage` => `CheckOutPage`.

But my issue is `Navigator.push()` create separate widget tree every time. So if I initialise a `Provider` in `SelectItemPage` this cannot be accessed in `ConfirmItemPage` or `CheckOutPage`.

I want `Provider` be scope to this flow, but I cannot see how.

How I can solve this? 
Or my approach is wrong?

**Edit**: I know I can use prop drilling for pass data from `SelectItemPage` => `ConfirmItemPage` => `CheckOutPage` but this hard to maintain. I want use `Provider` instead of prop drilling.

Comment: Does it help: https://dev.to/shakib609/create-a-todos-app-with-flutter-and-provider-jdh?  Where each tab is getting a list based on user action. Also state managemnet and Navigation shouldn't affect each other.

Comment: @skjagini Thanks for reply! But you article is not help. It just intialize Provider at top of widget tree. I want initialise lower and access lower in even after navigation.

Comment: If you need across the pages, you need it root level. If you don't like the way code is organized, you can check out Redux implementation, but again there is no other option.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's no other way, you mush initialize the provider on each class

try use like this on you app

on you main app

```
MultiProvider(
      providers: ChangeNotifierProvider<yourstate>(
          builder: (context) => yourstate,
        ),
child: MaterialApp...
```

on each page, you can initialize using below code

```
final state = Provider.of<yourstate>(context);
```

and use like this if you don't want to listen any change of the state

```
final state = Provider.of<yourstate>(context, listen: false);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! But is this not pollute scope?